# Display message or alternate View if Source of TableView is empty

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross' `MvxStandardTableViewSource` which is a `UITableViewSource`.

I have registered a custom cell for displaying the items in the Source. This all works as expected

```
        var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(this.TableView, new NSString("MyItemCell"));
        TableView.Source = source;
        TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 52.0f;
        TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(MyItemCell), new NSString("MyItemCell"));
```

The source for the TableViewSource is being driven by a Search so sometimes it could be empty.

What is the recommended way of communicating that there are no Search Results? Is it a custom UIView in the TableHeaderView or an additional CustomCell within the same TableHeaderView

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had was trying to see how I could insert extra UIViews around the table.

In the end I settled on the following approach.

1. Change the Controller to be an MvxViewController
2. New up a UITableView and bind it to an MvxStandardTableViewSource
3. Insert that and the UISearchBar just like any other views to the main
   controller's View
4. Insert any other necessary UIViews such as a Label for No Search Results just like you would normally rather than having to worry about TableHeaders